# How to combine Linux find, convert and copy commands into one command

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, jpeg

I have the following cmd that fetches all .pdf files with an STP pattern in the filename and places them into a folder:

```
find /home/OurFiles/Images/ -name '*.pdf' |grep "STP*" | xargs cp -t /home/OurFiles/ImageConvert/STP/
```

I have another cmd that converts pdf to jpg.

```
find /home/OurFiles/ImageConvert/STP/ -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file
    do convert -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 "${file}" "${file%.*}.jpg"

    done
```

Is it possible to combine these commands into one? Also, I would like pre-pend a prefix onto the converted image file name in the single command, if possible. Example: STP_OCTOBER.jpg to MSP-STP_OCTOBER.jpg. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: `-name '*.pdf' |grep "STP*" ` ? just `-name 'STP*.pdf'`. Yes, this looks possible and it this looks pretty easy and straightforward - just use `convert` as `cp`. Did you try changing anything? Do you understand the code you posted?

Comment: Also `grep` uses regex not glob. The `STP*` matches `ST` and any number of `P` (`*` means any number (_zero_ or more) of preceding character), like `STPPPPP` or `STP` or `ST`, in any position in the strnig, so `abcSTPdef` or `abcSTdef` are matched too. If you want to match strings starting from `STP` you want `grep '^STP'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /home/OurFiles/Images/ -type f -name '*STP*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  destination=$1; shift        # get the first argument
  for file do                  # loop over the remaining arguments
    fname=${file##*/}          # get the filename part
    cp "$file" "$destination" && 
      convert -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 "$destination/$fname" "$destination/MSP-${fname%pdf}jpg"
  done
' sh /home/OurFiles/ImageConvert/STP {} +
```

You could pass the destination directory and all PDFs found to `find`'s `-exec` option to execute a small script.
The script removes the first argument and saves it to variable `destination` and then loops over the given PDF paths. For each filepath, extract the filename, copy the file to the destination directory and run the `convert` command if the copy operation was successful.

Comment: Much appreciated. This works perfectly for what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
find /home/OurFiles/Images -type f -name 'STP*.pdf' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      destfile="/home/OurFiles/ImageConvert/STP/MSP-$(basename "$file" .pdf).jpg"
      convert -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 "$file" "$destfile"
  done
```

The only really new thing in this merged one compared to your two separate commands is using [`basename(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/basename.1.html) to strip off the directories and extension from the filename in order to create the output filename.